# nodejs express server not running/starting

Tags: node.js, express

I have created new express app using **express generator**.

After navigating to my app, when I try to run `node app.js` nothing happens.

I also tried to run it using nodemon package but server is still not running.

However when i set `SET DEBUG=NodeVue:* & npm start` and then use `npm start` command everything works fine..

Can anybody please explain me with why `node app.js` command is not working.

Thanks in advance.

app.js code -->

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var index = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

console window-- > [image]

Comment: Please post ur app.js code

Comment: Does the console window go away? Does it give an error? Tell us more about the problem, and show us some code.

Comment: @Gauravjoshi i have updated my question with app.js code. However this is the default code generated by express generator. I have not change anything in it.

Comment: @Tvde1 please refer the screenshot of my console window .. in updated question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you should try `node bin/www`，look into your package.json and check out the start script, it's the command you  should use.

Comment: @RohitWaghela app.js is not the entry file, www is.  Look for the shebang